# Removing Leading Zeros in a Char Array

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to subtract two strings (of theoretically infinite length) without the use of libraries like `BigInt`but I was wondering if anybody has any good ideas on how to remove the leading zeros in the corner cases like the one below?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Subtract("10", "10005"));
    }


    static string ReverseInput(string inputString)
    {
        char[] charArray = inputString.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(charArray);
        return new string(charArray);
    }

    static string Subtract(string firstNumInput, string secondNumInput)
    {
        string firstNum = String.Empty;
        string secondNum = String.Empty;
        bool negative = false;

        // Reverse order of string input
        if (firstNumInput.Length > secondNumInput.Length)
        {
            firstNum = ReverseInput(firstNumInput);
            secondNum = ReverseInput(secondNumInput); 
        }
        else if (firstNumInput.Length < secondNumInput.Length)
        {
            negative = true;
            firstNum = ReverseInput(secondNumInput);
            secondNum = ReverseInput(firstNumInput);
        }
        else if (firstNumInput.Length == secondNumInput.Length)
        {
            // iterate through string to find largest
        }

        char[] result = new char[firstNum.Length + 1]; 
        int resultLength = 0;
        int carry = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < firstNum.Length; i++)
        {
            int an = (i < firstNum.Length) ? int.Parse(firstNum[i].ToString()) : 0;
            int bn = (i < secondNum.Length) ? int.Parse(secondNum[i].ToString()) : 0;

            int rn = an - bn - carry;

            if (rn < 0)
            {
                carry = 1;
                rn += 10;
            }
            else
            {
                carry = 0;
            }

            result[resultLength++] = (char)(rn + '0');
        }

        // create the result string from the char array
        string finalResult = ReverseInput(new string(result, 0, resultLength));

        if (negative)
        {
            finalResult = '-' + finalResult;
        }

        return finalResult;
    }
```

Comment: `"I'm attempting to subtract two strings (of theoretically infinite length) without the use of libraries like BigInt"` - There is a `BigInteger` type in C#

Comment: I don't want to use the BigInt as I want to try and understand how libraries like BigInt are built, plus, I don't believe BigInt is entirely infinite.

Comment: In that case, why don't you just check out the [source (for `BigInteger`)](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Numerics/System/Numerics/BigInteger.cs)?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, what I meant to say is that I want to be able to carry out mathematical operations on numbers of very large length, in the form of strings, basically on numbers larger than what bigint can handle and in the process, hope to understand how bigint might work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for `TrimStart`?

```
    // create the result string from the char array
    string finalResult = ReverseInput(new string(result, 0, resultLength)).TrimStart('0');
```